# Open/Close on click JQuery

Tags: jquery

When the ID 'Home' is clicked in the following example, the div.panel will appear, and then if the ID 'Home' is clicked again, the div.panel is hidden. Currently I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#home').on('click', function() {
    $('div.panel').animate({
        'width': 'show'
    }, 1000, function() {
        $('div.home').fadeIn(500);
    });
});

$('#home').on('click', function() {
    $('div.home').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('div.panel').animate({
            'width': 'hide'
        }, 1000);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: And what's the problem with what you have?

Comment: It just opens and closes, as opposed to when clicked. I don't know JQuery very well and I know it needs to use 'toggle' ?

Comment: Couldn't you use http://api.jquery.com/toggle/?

Comment: Thanks j08691, unfortunately I am not familiar with JQuery hence my asking.

Comment: Can you also post your basic HTML structure, please?

Answer (score 5):

By duplicating the event handler as you are, both of those functions will attempt to run at the same time whenever `#home` is clicked. You need to use a conditional to decide whether to run one or the other.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#home').on('click', function () {
        if ($('div.home').is(':visible')) {
            $('div.home').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $('div.panel').animate({
                    'width': 'hide'
                }, 1000);
            });
        } else {
            $('div.panel').animate({
                'width': 'show'
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('div.home').fadeIn(500);
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is at one point redundant (the double defintion of `$('#home').on('click', function()...`), you need just one of them. To realise what you describe, jqueries' "[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)" is your friend. It could be done like this:

```
$('#home').on('click', function() {
    $('div.panel').animate({
        'width': 'toggle'
    }, 1000); });
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUcua/) for a working example.